# Why does Tesseract give poor performance on clean digits data?

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am working on a project to recognize a digital clock time from several images with tesseract.
Unfortunately most of the time it fails to recognize anything and gives me an empty result.

My tesseract version is 4.1.1.

To improve the quality of the recognitions, I did the following improvements:

- I whitelisted the characters that I am interested in with '-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789:.'
- converted the image to a binary image with black text on a white background
- fine tuned the english model with my data (~120 images and 500 iterations). I also tried to increase the number of iterations but it did not improve the performance of the model
- I saw on the tessdoc that the x-height should be somewhere between 20 and 30 px, so I rescaled my image.

````
```python
    import pytesseract 
    import math

    def read_time(filename):
        # 1st step whitelist charcters

        tesseract_config = '-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789:.  --psm 6'  

        # 2nd step convert image to binary

        clock_image = cv2.imread(filename)
        gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(clock_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        _, binary_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        # I created a small function to check if the current_background is white
        # if not I perform a bitwise_not operation on the image

        is_white_background = False

        if not is_white_background:
            binary_image = cv2.bitwise_not(binary_image)

        # 3rd step use a custom model that I created

        custom_model_config = '-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789:. -l my_custom_model --psm 6'

        # 4th step rescaled image to get my black characters between 20 and 30 pixels tall

        cnt_black_pixels_per_row = np.sum(binary_image == 0, axis=1)
        non_zero_lines = [n for n,i in enumerate(cnt_black_pixels_per_row) if i > 0]

        # get the first and the last line with at least a black pixel in it to estimate the current characters'height
        top, bottom = non_zero_lines[0], non_zero_lines[-1]
        
        current_height = abs(top - bottom)
        height_expected = 32
        new_height = math.floor(binary_image.shape[0] * height_expected / current_height)
        new_shape = (binary_image.shape[1], new_height)
        final_image = cv2.resize(binary_image, new_shape, interpolation= cv2.INTER_LINEAR)


        clock_text_binary = pytesseract.image_to_string(binary_image, config=tesseract_config)
        clock_text_binary_custom_config = pytesseract.image_to_string(binary_image, config=custom_model_config)
        clock_text_resized = pytesseract.image_to_string(final_image, config=custom_model_config)
        clock_text_resized_custom_config = pytesseract.image_to_string(final_image, config=tesseract_config)

        print(clock_text_binary, clock_text_binary_custom_config, clock_text_resized, clock_text_resized_custom_config)
```
````

I do not understand why I get such a poor performance considering that the data is quite clean and that tesseract seems to work pretty well on more difficult tasks.

I spent a lot of time and I feel that I am just going around in circles. If anyone has an idea to solve my problem I would be really greatful!

I have attached some examples of images that my script fails to recognize.

[image: image_0_original.png]
[image: image_0_white_background.png]
[image: image_1_original.png]
[image: image_1_white_background.png]

Thanks in advance,
H1t5uj1

Answer (score 0):

I get good results with this script:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

#image_file = "000_b.png" # I used your black background pictures
image_file = "908_b.png"

# load the input image, convert it from BGR to RGB channel ordering,
# and initialize our Tesseract OCR options as an empty string
image = cv2.imread(image_file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
print('Original Dimensions : ',image.shape)
 
scale_percent = 72 # percent of original size
width = int(rgb.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(rgb.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
  
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(rgb, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
print('Resized Dimensions : ',resized.shape)

grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) # 0 ...255
bw = cv2.imshow('Black white image', blackAndWhiteImage)

# Configuration
custom_config = r'--psm 7 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=01234567890:.'

# OCR the input image using Tesseract
tex = pytesseract.image_to_string(blackAndWhiteImage, config=custom_config)
print(tex)

# write result to text file
with open("numbers.txt", 'a') as f:
    f.writelines(tex)

cv2.imshow('Resized', resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]